# Linux kernel ARM Translation table base (TTB0 and TTB1)

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, arm

Compiled Linux kernel 2.6.34.3 for ARMv7 (Cortex-a8)

I looked into the kernel code and it looks like the Linux kernel sets the hardware page tables for the kernel address space (everything over 0xC0000000)on TTB1 (translation table base) and the user process on ttb0 (everything under 0xC0000000) which changes for every process context switch. Is this correct? I'm still confused how the MMU knows which ttb to look at for translations?

I read that the TTBCR (translation table base control register) determines which of the ttb register to walk when an MVA is not found, however the register always reads 0 which means always use TTBR0 in the ARM architecture reference manual. How is that possible? Can anyone explain to me how the Linux kernel uses these two ttbs?

I read how the ttb works from this site https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/10-paging.html but I still dont understand how the kernel use the two ttbs

(Double checked the kernel code, for some reason both ttb0 and ttb1 is set, but it seems like ttb1 is never used, i set the TTB1 register to 0 and the Linux kernel continue to run as usual)

Comment: On the link you enclosed, `TTBR0 will still contain the memory map for the operating system and memory-mapped I/O.`, I guess they meant to say `TTBR1 will still contain the memory map for the operating system and memory-mapped I/O.`, which makes much more sense toward the 3G/1G (2G/2G) memory split. `TTBR0` maps process AS with address from 0 to 0xbfffffff, `TTBR0` is switched during each process switch. `TTBR1` is never modified since it contains the link to the kernel AS (starting at 0xc000000 on a Linux with a 3G/1G split).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, so is it correct that for each table walk the hardware ONLY uses TTB0? The hardware does not use the TTBCR to determine which of the ttb register to walk? So TTB1 is only used to copy OS pages to the process pages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The TTBR registers are used together to determine addressing for the full 32-bit or 40-bit address space.  Which register is used for what address ranges is controlled via the tXsz bits in the TTBCR.  There is an entry for t0sz corresponding to TTBR0 and t1sz for TTBR1.

The page tables addressed by each TTBRx register are independent, but you typically find most Linux implementations just use TTBR0.  Linux expects to be able to use a 3G/1G address space partitioning scheme, which is not supported by ARM.  If you look at page B3-1345 of the ARMv7 Architecture Reference Manual, you'll see that the value of t0sz and t1sz determine the address ranges supported by TTBR0 and TTBR1 respectively.  To add confusion to disorientation, it is even possible to have disjoined address spaces where TTBR0 and TTBR1 support ranges that are not contiguous, resulting in a hole in the system address space.  Good times!

To answer your main question though, it is recommended by ARM that TTBR0 be used to store the offset to the page tables used by USER processes, and TTBR1 be used to store the offset to the page tables used by the KERNEL.  I have yet to see a single implementation that actually does this.  Almost exclusively TTBR0 is used in all cases, with TTBR1 containing a duplicate copy of the L1 tables.

So how does this work?  The value of TTBR is stored as part of the process state and simply restored each time a process with switched out.  This is how it is expected to work.  Originally, TTBR1 would hold a constant value for the kernel tables and never be replaced or swapped out, whereas TTBR0 would be changed each time you context switch between processes.  Apparently most Linux implementations for ARM have decided to just basically eliminate the use of TTBR1 and stick to using TTBR0 for everything.

If you want to test this theory on your device, try whacking TTBR1 and watch nothing happen.  Then try whacking TTBR0 and watch your system crash.  I've yet to encounter a single instance that didn't result in this exact same result.  Long story short, TTBR1 is useless by Linux, and TTBR0 is used almost exclusively and simply swapped out.

Now, once you get to LPAE support, throw all this away and start over again.  This is the implementation where you will start to see the value of t0sz and t1sz being something other than zero, and hence N as well.

Comment: As an extra bit of information, check out this link. http://linuxkernelarticles.blogspot.com/2013/03/updating-ttbr-in-arm-during-context.html

Comment: isn't the 3G/1G address space partitioning obtained for T0SZ=0 and T1SZ=2?

Answer (score 1):

I have very little knowledge about ARM architecture, but from what I read in your enclosed link, then I guess Linux implements its virtual-memory management that way:

> High-order bits of the virtual address determine which one to use. The base of the table is stored in one of two base registers (TTBR0 or TTBR1), depending on whether the topmost n bits of the virtual address are 0 (use TTBR0) or not (use TTBR1). The value for n is defined by the Translation Table Base Control Register (TTBCR).

The register `TTBCR` tells which addresses will be translated from page-tables pointed to by `TTBR0` or `TTBR1`. If `TTBCR` contains `0xc000000`, then any address from `0` to `0xbfffffff` is translated by the page-table pointed by `TTBR0`, and any address from `0xc0000000` to `0xffffffff` is translated by the page-table pointed by `TTBR1`. That match the Linux memory-split of 3GB for user process / 1GB for the kernel.

> This allows one to have a design where the operating system and memory-mapped I/O are located in the upper part of the address space and managed by the page table in TTBR1 and user processes are in the lower part of memory and managed by the page table in TTB0. On a context switch, the operating system has to change TTBR0 to point to the first-level table for the new process. **TTBR1** will still contain the memory map for the operating system and memory-mapped I/O.

Hence, the value of `TTBR1` should never change because you want the kernel to be permanently mapped (think of what happens when an interrupt is raised). On the other hand, `TTBR0` is modified at every process-switch, it contains the page-table of the current process.

Comment: "if bits [31:32-N] of the Virtual Address are all 0, use Translation Table Base Register 0 otherwise use Translation Table Base Register 1"   There is no N value that can separate the kernel address(>= 0xC0000000) and user address(< 0xC0000000. Lets say N is the minimum value 1, then the maximum Virtual addresses is 0x7FFFFFFF, which means smaller addresses uses TTB0 and everything larger will use TTB1. Its not possible to set a N value to satisfy the 3GB:1GB user/kernel address split (2:2 works though).

Comment: Your description of how TTBCR is used to determine whether or not TTBR0 or TTBR1 apply is incorrect. MrGigu's comment is correct.  The maximum virtual address usable by TTBR0 (when also using TTBR1) is 0x7fffffff.

Answer (score 1):

See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0211k/Bihgfcgf.html

For ARM5 and lower the TTB table is fixed in size and alignment (to 16k).  Each level 1 entry represents 1MB.  The table entry is 32bits  (16k*1M/(32bit/8) = 4GB).  The *TTBCR* controls *TTBR0* table size.  From the above URL,

> **Selecting which Translation Table Base Register is used** 
>   The Translation Table Base Register is selected as follows: 
>   If N = 0, always use Translation Table Base Register 0. 
>   - This is the default case at reset. It is backwards compatible with ARMv5 or earlier processors. 
>   If N is greater than 0, then: 
>   - if bits [31:32-N] of the Virtual Address are all 0, use Translation Table Base Register 0 otherwise use Translation Table Base Register 1.

So the size of *TTBR0* also sets the memory split.  For a <strike>traditional</strike> Linux <strike>3G/1G</strike> 1G/3G, the value **2** should be selected. 4kB table == 1G memory == bits 31..30 are zero.  For a value of **6** the table is 256byte == 64MB == bits 31..26 are zero.

In Linux parlance these are *page global* entries (and this splits this *page global* directory).  The entries can point to another table or just be a 1MB **segment**.  The next table entries are *page middle* Linux directories and then the final *page table* entries.  I think the *page middle* entries are unused on the ARM.

The MMU hardware doesn't walk the tables every time. There is a TLB (translation look aside buffer). It is like a cache for the MMU tables.  When the OS updates these tables, the TLB must be flushed or the processor will use *stale* entries.  Similarly the ARM cache is *virtual tagged*, so changing the mapping may also mean the *cache* must be flushed.  For these reasons, you **never** want to change things on a context switch. Shared libraries text (say **libc.so**) should be the same on a context switch.  Hopefully each process has libc.so mapped at the same virtual address.  There is a big gain in doing this; lower memory use and good I-cache use.

The *domain* and *PID* registers as well as supervisor/user modes can also control memory accesses.  These are single registers that can be toggled on a context switch.

See http://lwn.net/images/conf/rtlws11/papers/proc/p01.pdf for info on PID and domain use on the ARMV5. The current Linux source doesn't do exactly like the paper describes.  It is entirely possible that Linux doesn't need to use this mechanism and sets the *TTBCR* to zero so that the VM code for ARM sub-architectures is similar.

**Edit:**  I **don't** believe the *TTBCR* functionality can be used to achieve a 3G/1G split.  I think the Rutger's page was discussing the *TTBCR* generically and not in the **Linux** context.  Also, at least the **2.6.38** Linux used *domains* or *DACR* but does not use the *pid* or *fcse* as it supports a limited number of processes.

http://lwn.net/Articles/106177/ - also referenced on the Rutgers page.

Comment: Interesting paper, however using of the FCSE limits each process to 32MB which I don't think a normal Linux distribution will enforce on the user. However for constrained embedded devices it seems feasible.

Comment: Im still confused, setting the N bit to 2, if means all virtual addresses <= 0x3FFF FFFF will use TTB0 and larger use TTB1. How is this a 3GB:1GB user/kernel split?

Comment: The split is 1G/3G (as per edit), and this functionality is most likely unused by Linux. Also, *fcse* is deprecated on newer ARM CPUs.

Comment: See: [Catalin Marinas's ARM LPAE paper](http://elinux.org/images/6/6a/Elce11_marinas.pdf) for use of TTBR1 in Linux LPAE.

Answer (score 0):

The TTBR0 holds the base address of translation table 0, and information about the memory it occupies.

This is one of the translation tables for the stage 1 translation of memory accesses from modes other than Hyp mode