# ARM Linux kernel page table

Tags: linux, arm, mmu

Ref. [Linux kernel ARM Translation table base (TTB0 and TTB1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460752/linux-kernel-arm-translation-table-base-ttb0-and-ttb1)

I have father doubt/query on topic discussed in previous link:

> 1. 0 to 0xbfffffff  is a lower part of memory (for user processes) and managed by the page table in TTB0, it contains the page-table of the current process
>
>    > Ref. arm/include/asm/pgtable-2level.h : PTRS_PER_PGD =2048, PTRS_PER_PMD =1, PTRS_PER_PTE =512
> 2. 0xc0000000 to 0xffffffff is upper part (OS and memory-mapped I/O) of the address space managed/translated by the page table in TTBR1.
>      TTB1 table is fixed in size and alignment (to 16k). Each level 1 entry of size is 32bits and represents 1MB page/segment.  This is `swapper_pg_dir` (ref `System.map`) page tables that placed 16K below the actual text address

1. Is that the first 768 entry in `swapper_pg_dir = 0`  (0x0 to 0xbfffffff for user processes) and valid entry from 768 to 1024(0xc0000000 to 0xffffffff is for OS and memory-mapped I/O)?
2. Anyone like to share some sample code in kernel space (kernel module) to browse this `swapper_pg_dir` PGD?

Comment: If you read the cited thread, TTB0/TTB1 is not used.  Only one version is used.  The splitting is wrong for the typical Linux memory model.  It maybe beneficial for other OSs.

Comment: Thx for your update. would you please confirm - (1) each entry in swapper_pg_dir corresponds to a 1MB section of memory? (2)Any example to traverse the PGD list (each entry 8byte, and 2048 entries)?

Answer (score 7):

Because of how the ARM MMU was designed, both the translations tables (TTB0 and TTB1) can only be used in a 1:1 mapping kernel mapping.

Most Linux Kernels have a 3:1 mapping (3GB User space : 1GB Kernel space for ARM). 
This means that 0-0xBFFFFFFF is user space while 0xC0000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF is kernel space.

Now for the HW memory translations, only TTBR0 is used. TTBR1 only holds the address of the initial swapper page (which contains all the kernel mappings) and isn't really used for virtual address translations. TTBR0 hold the address for the current used page directory (the page table that the HW is using for translations). Now each user process has their own page tables, and for each process switch, TTBR0 changes to the current user process page table (they are all located in kernel space).

For example, for each new user process, the kernel creates a new page directory, copies all the kernel mappings from the swapper page(page frames from 3-4GB) to the new page table and clears the user pages(page frames from 0-3GB). It then sets TTB0 to the base address of this page directory and flushes cache to install the new address space. The swapper page is also always kept up to date with changes to the mappings.

For your question:

1. Simplified, hardwarewise the first level page have 4096 entries. Each entry represent 1MB of virtual address, totalling 4GB of ram. Entry 0-3071 represent user space and entry 3072-4095 represent kernel space.
2. The swapper page is usually located at address 0xC0004000 - 0xc0008000 (4096 entries *4bytes each entry = 16384 =16kb in hex = 0x4000 ). By examing the memory at 0xc0004000-0xc0007000 you can find entries for user space (empty) and from 0xc0007000-0xc0008000 you can find kernel entries. I use gdb with the command line `x /100x 0xc0007000` in order to examine the first 100 kernel entries. You can then examine the technical reference manual for your current platform in order to decipher the page table attributes.

If you want to learn more about the Linux kernel, I recommend you to use Qemu to simulate the Beagleboard together with gdb to examine and debug the source code. I did this to learn how the kernel builds the page table during initialization.

Comment: MrGigu, would you please let me know what you mean by "TTBR0 hold the address for the current used page directory (the page table that the HW is using for translations). I am having hard time understanding that page tables are maintained at both OS level and H/W level(which is MMU), so what you are saying that page directory(first level of page table) is set up Linux OS that has only virtual addresses and when these virtual addresses are feed  to HW(MMU unit) as an input , output from MMU is a Physical Address  , I didn't understand how Harware Page tables are used in this Process ?

Comment: Hello Amit, the page tables are located somewhere in RAM, for 32 bit Linux ARM, its usually at virtual address 0xc0004000 - 0xc0008000. So the page table contains 4096 entries which each take 4 byte, thats 16KB of space. For simplicity, If we assume that each entry is mapped as a 1MB section page, then entry 0 maps the virtual address 0, entry 1 address 0x0100 0000, entry 2 address 0x0200 0000 etc up to 0xFFF0 0000, i.e total of 4GB of RAM.

Comment: continue from last message: Now each page entry can be mapped to a custom physical address, so if entry 1 is mapped to address 0x0a00 0000, then all accesses to virtual address 0x0100 0000 will be translated to physical address 0x0a00 0000. This is the page table located at software, that the hardware MMU look at for translation for each access in the virtual address space. The MMU also has a cache called the TLB, where the most recent and often translated entries are cached in the system.